# Apache MQ Scanning Message

Tags: java, apache, activemq-classic

I am new to Apache Active Message Queues.
While reading(Consuming) the messages from MQ, the de-queue count increasing and that message deleting from MQ storage. 
Here, I want to scan the message without deleting the message from MQ and de-queue count as same. means, just I want scan the message and storing it local or printing it at output.

Can Any body Suggest on this? I want to implement it using java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an [ActiveMQQueueBrowser](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQQueueBrowser.html). You can find an example code [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/activemq/activemq-core/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/JmsQueueBrowserTest.java.shtml).

*But you need to be careful with this approach.* Messaging Queues are not designed for this kind of access, only some implementations (like ActiveMQ) provides this access-type for special use-cases. It should be used only if really necessary, and you need to understand the limitations of this:

- The returned enumeration might not fetch the full content of the queue
- The enumeration might contain a message that has been already dequeued by the time you process it

etc.